# Crop GLES texture before drawing

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview

I'm using a SurfaceView to render the Camera preview to the screen via GLES. Is it possible to crop the texture in the method below before it is rendered? I'd like to crop a 16:9 texture to appear as 4:3 on the screen.

```
public void drawFrame(int width, int height, float sourceAspectRatio, float targetAspectRatio, boolean flipHorizontally, boolean flipVertically) {

    //Aspect ratio correction. Source Aspect ratio is taken from Camera.Parameters.getPictureSize()
    //assuming that value is the native resolution of the camera. Sometimes the native camera aspect ratio
    //doesn't match the display's aspect ratio.
    float scaleX, scaleY;
    if (sourceAspectRatio >= targetAspectRatio) {
        scaleX = sourceAspectRatio/targetAspectRatio;
        scaleY = 1;
    } else {
        scaleX = 1;
        scaleY = targetAspectRatio/sourceAspectRatio;
    }

    if (flipHorizontally) scaleX = -scaleX;
    if (flipVertically) scaleY = -scaleY;

    checkGlError("onDrawFrame start");
    mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);

    GLES20.glViewport(0,0,width,height);

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    checkGlError("glUseProgram");

    /**
     * Explanation of double binding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386515/glsurfaceview-framerate-issues-on-nexus-5
     *
     * I was able to replicate the behavior, and my GL wizard office-mate figured out the problem.
     * Basically, one of the EGL contexts isn't noticing that the texture contents have changed, so it keeps rendering older data.
     * We think it's getting occasional updates because it has a set of buffers that it cycles through,
     * so eventually it re-uses the buffer you're looking at.
     * I was able to fix the problem in my code by updating the texture renderer class, changing this:
     *
     * GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID)
     *
     * to this
     *
     * GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
     * GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
     *
     * The un-bind and re-bind causes the driver to pick up the right buffer.
     */
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");

    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
    mMVPMatrix[0] = scaleX;
    mMVPMatrix[5] = scaleY;
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I'm nut sure this is the right way to crop a texture, but it does what I need. I just set negative values to the starting coordinates of the view port and resized the resolution according to the output I need:

```
public void drawFrame(int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int targetWidth, int targetHeight, boolean flipHorizontally, boolean flipVertically) {

    int offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;
    float scaleX = 1, scaleY = 1;
    if (flipHorizontally) scaleX = -scaleX;
    if (flipVertically) scaleY = -scaleY;

    float sourceAspectRatio = (float) sourceWidth / sourceHeight;
    float targetAspectRatio = (float) targetWidth / targetHeight;

    //Pull the image off the screen if needed, based on the aspect ratio diff.
    if (sourceAspectRatio > targetAspectRatio) {
        int scaledTargetWidth = (int) (targetHeight * sourceAspectRatio);
        offsetX = (scaledTargetWidth - targetWidth) / 2;
        offsetX = -offsetX;
        targetWidth = scaledTargetWidth;
    } else if (sourceAspectRatio < targetAspectRatio) {
        int scaledTargetHeight = (int) (targetWidth / sourceAspectRatio);
        offsetY = (scaledTargetHeight - targetHeight) / 2;
        offsetY = -offsetY;
        targetHeight = scaledTargetHeight;
    }

    checkGlError("onDrawFrame start");
    mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);

    GLES20.glViewport(offsetX,offsetY,targetWidth,targetHeight);

    //TODO....
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just change your texture coordinates (to pick what you want to appear on screen), and your vertex coordinates (to decide where on screen you draw).